# Parsed_response in Ruby from HTTP

Tags: ruby, http

How can i get parsed_response from here?

```
require 'HTTParty'
require 'httparty/request'
require 'httparty/response/headers'

class CRUD
   include HTTParty

   def retrieve
        @@response = CRUD.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/id') 
   end 
end
```

> {"id":"719","employee_name":"test","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""}

`puts @manter_user.retrieve.parsed_response['employee_name']`               -- dont work

`puts CRUD.class_variable_get(:@@response).parsed_response['employee_name']` -- dont work

Comment: `{"id":"719","employee_name":"test","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""}` is this a JSON response?

Comment: Yes, Json!!. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an instance method, it means that you need to create an instance. And you don't need global variable. And it is bad idea to name class with all uppercase letters - this style is used for constants. Classes and modules use MixedCase and have no underscores, each word starts with an uppercase letter.

```
class Crud    
  include HTTParty

  def retrieve    
    self.class.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee/id') 
  end
end

> Crud.new.retrieve.parsed_response
```

Comment: Vasilia
Thanks for the great tips, I'll adjust right now.

Comment: Hello, I made all the changes you suggested !! .. Thank you very much for the lesson !.

Comment: @saulik happy to help :)

Comment: Hi can you help me one more time?.

Comment: @saulik just post a new question and send me a link here in comments

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the JSON response, you can parsed it back as

```
require 'json'
foo = JSON['{"id":"719","employee_name":"test","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""}']
puts foo['employee_name'] # => test
```

Comment: Hi, thank you!!!.. Do you know Automated Tests with Ruby and Cucumber?,

Comment: @saulik please accept the answer, if this worked for you. Please try to search for the Automated Tests with Ruby and Cucumber and if the results didn't satisfy you, you can post a question here in Stackoverflow.

Comment: @SantoshAryal the problem was not in JSON parsing